# Pointer at declaration of "typedef struct"

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef, declaration

Could somebody please explain to beginner "C" programmer what is `*sometext`? How can i use it? First `sometext` is name of structure as i undestand.

```
typedef struct
{
   ULONG x;
   ULONG y;
} SOMETEXT, *SOMETEXT;
```

Comment: I suggest that you read a beginners book about `C`

Comment: It's a syntax error.

Comment: its not syntax error, its real driver code replaced with different field name

Comment: The compiler says it is a syntax error. As pointed out in the answer. You must post the real code, not imaginary.

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to:

```
struct unnamed_type_that_im_giving_a_name_to_here {
   ULONG x;
   ULONG y;
};

struct unnamed_type_that_im_giving_a_name_to_here SOMETEXT;
struct unnamed_type_that_im_giving_a_name_to_here *SOMETEXT;
```

Note that this is invalid code since you're delcaring `SOMETEXT` twice. But I'm assuming that in your actual code those are different names.

Answer (score 0):

Using one typedef you can introduce several aliases for types.

Here is a simple demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int INT_TYPE, *INT_PTR;

int main(void) 
{
    INT_TYPE x = 10;
    INT_PTR p = &x;

    printf( "x = %d\n", *p );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x = 10
```

Here in the program the typedef introduces two aliases: `INT_TYPE` for the type `int` and `INT_PTR` for the type `int *`.

As for your example of a typedef then for starters it is invalid becuase the same identifier `SOMETEXT` is used to declare two different types in the scope.

However if to rename the second identifier as for example `SOMETEXT_PTR` then this typedef

```
typedef struct
{
   ULONG x;
   ULONG y;
} SOMETEXT, *SOMETEXT_PTR;
```

you can imagine like two separate typedefs

```
typedef struct
{
   ULONG x;
   ULONG y;
} SOMETEXT;

typedef SOMETEXT *SOMETEXT_PTR;
```

That is `SOMETEXT` is an alias for an unnamed structure and `SOMETEXT_PTR` is an alias for the type pointer to the unnamed structure.

Answer (score 0):

I see below:-

```
typedef struct SOMETEXT
{
   ULONG x;
   ULONG y;
};
```

Here we have declared a `struct` (structure) which name is `SOMETEXT` and that is why this kind of declaration is call user define type.

So now we are using the name of the struct like below:-

```
  struct SOMETEXT  *s, *p, *q;
```

So in the above code we have declared 3 pointer of type SOMETEXT. And if you noticed every time we are using struct in front of name `SOMETEXT`. To avoid that we will provide a alias  to SOMETEXT like below:-

```
  typedef struct SOMETEXT1
  {
    ULONG x;
    ULONG y;
  } *SOMETEXT;
```

so now we can declare pointer of SOMETEXT like below:-

```
  SOMETEXT s, p, q;
```

Here we don't need to use `*` in front of each variable. This is same as previous declaration of `struct SOMETEXT  *s, *p, *q;`

Comment: When your `typedef` doesn't have a name after `struct` definition (like `typedef struct X {whatever}`), the use of `typedef` is useless. It also generates a warning.

Comment: @anatolyg, yes true. Respect your comment and I have modified my answer. Thanks :-)